# Android AVD + Eclipse: How to remove a directory from Android File Explorer?

Tags: android, eclipse, file, explorer, android-virtual-device

I'm using eclipse to run developing apk.

I can delete file that apk created into from mnt/sdcard-

But i'm not able to delete create folders. The red minus icon is grayed and disabled when I click on a folder, but it's enabled and red when i click on a file.

So, how to delete a folder ? 
I cannot destroy sdcard every time, i'm downloading a very complex folder structure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can connect to the Android Emulator instance via `adb`. This allows you to delete files and folder via command-line.

Just execute `adb shell rm -r /mnt/sdcard/yourfoldername`

Comment: Is there really no way to delete from explorer ? Why is the motivation to disallow this ?

Comment: Android File Explorer is an open source project. If you think this is a bug you should open a bug request in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android-file-explorer/issues/list).